.Net 6 StreamReader.ReadBlockAsync throw System.ObjectDisposedException when reading file
I have a problem when trying to read a file from an FTP server. Thousands of files have been read without problem. This problem only occurs for 1 file. The problem occurs when I use the method ReadBlockAsync() from the StreamReader
readLength = await sr.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, 0, settings.ReadBufferLength);
I get a System.ObjectDisposedException
Exception
Here is the complete method I use :
private async Task ReadFile(string fromFilePath, string file, Func<ReadFileData, Task> callback)
{
    FtpWebResponse response = null;
    Stream responseStream = null;
    StreamReader sr = null;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromFilePath) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
        return;

    string path = Path.Combine(fromFilePath, file);

    // Create FTP request
    if (WebRequest.Create(path) is not FtpWebRequest request)
    {
        logger.LogError($"FileManagementFtp: Impossible to create FTP for {path}");

        return;
    }

    request.Credentials = networkCredential;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

    try
    {
        // Send request
        response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as FtpWebResponse;
        if (response != null)
        {
            // Get response
            responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                char[] buffer = new char[settings.ReadBufferLength];
                int readLength;
                ReadFileData readFileData = new ReadFileData
                {
                    FileChunk = 0
                };

                // Read file
                sr = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

                do
                {
                    readLength = await sr.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, 0, settings.ReadBufferLength);

                    readFileData.FileChunk++;
                    readFileData.FileContent = new string(buffer, 0, readLength);
                    readFileData.IsComplete = readLength < settings.ReadBufferLength;

                    await callback(readFileData);
                } while (!readFileData.IsComplete);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        logger.LogError($"FileManagementFtp: Method name {nameof(ReadFile)} - Status description {((FtpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.LogError($"FileManagementFtp: Method name {nameof(ReadFile)} - Error : {e.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
            response.Dispose();
        }

        if (responseStream != null)
        {
            responseStream.Close();
            responseStream.Dispose();
        }

        if (sr != null)
        {
            sr.Close();
            sr.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

This is the WebResponse :
WebResponse
This is the ResponseStream :
ResponseStream
I found 2 solutions to the problem.
First when I convert the Stream to a MemoryStream no exception is thrown
// Send request
response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as FtpWebResponse;
if (response != null)
{
    // Get response
    responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    if (responseStream != null)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await responseStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        char[] buffer = new char[settings.ReadBufferLength];
        int readLength;
        ReadFileData readFileData = new ReadFileData
        {
            FileChunk = 0
        };

        // Read file
        sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

        do
        {
            readLength = await sr.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, 0, settings.ReadBufferLength);

            readFileData.FileChunk++;
            readFileData.FileContent = new string(buffer, 0, readLength);
            readFileData.IsComplete = readLength < settings.ReadBufferLength;

            await callback(readFileData);
        } while (!readFileData.IsComplete);
    }
}

Second if I read the stream byte by byte
if (responseStream != null)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[10000];
    int readLength;
    ReadFileData readFileData = new ReadFileData
    {
        FileChunk = 0
    };

    // Read file
    sr = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
    int i = 0;
    List<char> list = new List<char>();
    do
    {
        readLength = await sr.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, i, 1);

        list.Add(buffer[i]);

        i++;

    } while (readLength > 0);
}

These 2 solutions works. But I don't understand why this exception is thrown when I read the entire stream.
If anyone can explain it to me, I would be grateful.
May the code be with you :)
